# How to take X- Axis and Y- axis lines to Bar Charts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using BarChart library in swift.https://github.com/nhatminh12369/BarChart

I created the bar chart. But I am not able to set the X-axis and Y-axis to bar chart and i am not able to set array to barchart in place of date displaying(i.e 17 Aug 18). Please help me!

I need this type of result. Please see below image:

[image]

Below code is what I am using:

```
func generateDataEntries() -> [BarEntry] {

    let colors = [UIColor.red,UIColor.gray,UIColor.blue,UIColor.green,UIColor.black,UIColor.brown,UIColor.cyan]
    var result: [BarEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<6 {
        let value = (arc4random() % 90) + 10
        let height: Float = Float(value) / 100.0

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM"
        var date = Date()
        date.addTimeInterval(TimeInterval(24*60*60*i))
        result.append(BarEntry(color: colors[i % colors.count], height: height, textValue: "\(value)", title: formatter.string(from: date)))
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by x&y. I think you are saying position or origin of bar chart

Comment: @bhatejaud: i mean origin

Comment: Are you giving the class in storyboard or adding the bar chart to subview progrmatically?

Comment: @bhatejaud: I am giving the class in storyboard

Comment: @bhatejaud: i am adding one view to view controller in storyboard. that view i am adding class name as "BasicBarChart" in storyboard

Comment: Make sure your constraints are correct. I did the same and they are coming fine.

Comment: @bhatejaud: Plz send me the code what u r using for that

Answer (score 1):

Pls download the modified copy of **BasicBarChart.swift** from this link: 
[Download Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YbH9cWhxVQVf0xnk_SmTj5Rnf1Zf3fUo)

Now you can draw your x-Axis by calling the function: drawXAxis(from: Int, to: Int, step: Int)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var basicBarChart: BasicBarChart!
    @IBOutlet weak var barChart: BeautifulBarChart!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        stackOverflowData()
    }

    func stackOverflowData()
    {
        let colors: [UIColor]   = [UIColor.yellow, UIColor.brown, UIColor.blue, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.cyan]
        let titles: [String]    = ["Dog", "Cat", "Goldfish", "Birds", "Hamster"]
        let values: [Int]       = [7, 6, 5, 2, 3]

        var dataEntries: [BarEntry] = []
        for i in 0...4
        {
            dataEntries.append(BarEntry(color: colors[i], height: Float(values[i])/10.0, textValue: "\(values[i])", title: titles[i]))
        }

        basicBarChart.dataEntries = dataEntries
        basicBarChart.drawXAxis(from: 0, to: 9, step: 1)
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it's nice but we missed a X-axis line in that BarChart & removing top line also. Plz guide me!

Comment: You can do that easily by just modifying a few methods. 
In BasicBarChart.swift, go to **drawHorizontalLines()** and modify it for top line; **drawXAxis()** will be used for drawing a vertical line.

Comment: i am trying but i'm not get result, plz help me how to draw X-Axis() in BarChart

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var basicBarChart: BasicBarChart!
    @IBOutlet weak var barChart: BeautifulBarChart!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        stackOverflowData()
    }

    func stackOverflowData()
    {
        let colors: [UIColor]   = [UIColor.yellow, UIColor.brown, UIColor.blue, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.cyan]
        let titles: [String]    = ["Dog", "Cat", "Goldfish", "Birds", "Hamster"]
        let values: [Int]       = [7, 6, 5, 2, 3]

        var dataEntries: [BarEntry] = []
        for i in 0...4
        {
            dataEntries.append(BarEntry(color: colors[i], height: Float(values[i])/10.0, textValue: "\(values[i])", title: titles[i]))
        }

        basicBarChart.dataEntries = dataEntries
        barChart.dataEntries = dataEntries
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Simulator]

basicBarChart & barChart are assigned in storyboard with constraints.

Comment: nice fine but i need one more thing is how can i add X-axis and Y- Axis for that bar char. plz help and see once above image what i am post

Comment: For y-axis use title parameter in bar entry's init method. X-axis as shown by you is different and for this the library needs to be modified. Pls wait for some time, I will post the updated code soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Plz send me code after completed i will wait for that.

Comment: Hi, it's completed, plz help me!